# send parameters from ajax to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, controller

the error is: The identifier id is missing for a query of Cocktails\RecipesBundle\Entity\Ingredient

So, the problem is that controller doesn't get the parameter ingredientId, I've tried many examples and tutorials but nothing helped. maybe there's some easy obvious mistake which I am missing? How could I pass parameters from ajax function to controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new and empty Request object which obviously doesn't have the request information of the current request... it will be empty.

You can add a parameter to `addIngredientToUser` called `$request` and using type-hinting as `Request $request`. This way Symfony2 will give you the **actual** request object of the current request populated with the correct request information.

Comment: and what should i send in ajax as a parameter to controllers parameter $request?

Comment: You don't need to send anything, `Request $request`, `Post $post` and a few other parameters of action functions don't have to be explicitly passed, they are automatically filled in by Symfony2.

Comment: Try to debug -- check if the post data reaches your controller by using `var_dump($_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST);`

Comment: all three arrays are empty. why doesn't it reach controller? maybe it's because it's going through routing and parameters dont get passed?

Comment: when changing POST to GET it shows that parameters are passed (var dump `array(1) {
  ["{"ingredient":"2"}"]=>
  string(0) ""
}` but i'm still not able to reach it

Comment: finally got it working! it was something with datatypes. when i deleted datatype and contenttype, i was finally able to reach the variable. thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Working code are

```
public function addIngredientToUserAction(Request $request) {
    $usr = $this->getUser();
    $id = $request->get('ingredient');
    $ingredientEntity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CocktailsRecipesBundle:Ingredient')->find($id);
    $usr->addIngredient($ingredientEntity);

    return $this->render('CocktailsRecipesBundle:Default:menu.html.twig');
}
```

In your comment for previous answer you have made a mistake

```
$id = $request->get('id');
                     ^^ - should be 'ingredient'
```

Comment: sorry about that, one comment(now deleted) suggested changing var names and so i did. this is not the case, it still doesnt work even with ingredient

Comment: Could you please do alert(ingredient) in JS before ajax() call?